# Entering an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, parity

In this segment of code, from everything I'm seeing, it should be entering the `for` loop and then the `if` statement as long as you enter 1's and 0's, which is what I'm doing. It's not entering it, as I've seen from my print statements.

I don't see a reason why.

If it did enter the `if` statement, I also am unsure what to do because my suspicion is that it will only set `true` if the last bit is not a 1 or 0: my intention being for `zeroesAndOnes` to be `false` if anything except 1's and 0's are entered. However, as it stands, it's `false` all the time.

```
 System.out.println("Please enter a 32 bit number consisting of "
                        + "1's and 0's.");
    String number = kb.nextLine();
    int count = 0;
    boolean zeroesAndOnes = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++){

        if(number.charAt(i) == '0' || number.charAt(i) == '1'){

            zeroesAndOnes = true;
            System.out.println("If boolean " + zeroesAndOnes);
        }

        else{

            zeroesAndOnes = false;
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("If boolean end " + zeroesAndOnes);


    if(number.length() == 32 && count > 1){

        if(number.charAt(0) + number.charAt(1) % 2 == 1){
            symmDiff = 1;
            }
        else{
            symmDiff = 0;
        }
for(int i = 2; i < number.length(); i++){

                if((symmDiff + number.charAt(i)) % 2 == 1){
                    symmDiff = 1;
                }
                else{
                    symmDiff = 0;
                }

            }

            System.out.println("The parity bit for this number is " + symmDiff);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("These numbers do not match the specification.");
        }
```

Comment: `number.charAt(i) == 0` You are probably looking to compare char values here eg `number.charAt(i) == '0'`

Comment: Thank you! That fixed that problem. Do you happen to have any ideas about the second portion--with how I have it now, the end bit determines whether it is true or false. I wanted it to be true only if ALL the bits are 1 or 0, but I can't think of anything.

Comment: Stop setting it to `true` when you find a `'1'` or `'0'`. Initialize the boolean to `true` instead of `false`, and only set it to `false` when there's a violation. Never set it back to `true` once it's `false`.

Answer (score 2):

When checking for char equality, be sure the comparison is what you need. For instance

```
if(number.charAt(i) == 0)
```

checks for decimal value equality. To check for an actual '0' char, compare the char value

```
if ( number.charAt(i) == '0' )
```

Comment: Thank you, as well! I'll ask you, too-- Do you have any ideas about the second portion--with how I have it now, the end bit determines whether it is true or false. I wanted it to be true only if ALL the bits are 1 or 0, but I can't think of anything.

Comment: You can validate the user input in several ways. One might be to count each correct value, then check if this count is equal to the expected length - if so set `zeroesAndOnes ` to true

Comment: I added the rest of my code above, and I had a similar thought just before I read this to use a count on the false value. But now, no matter what I put in, I always get my "These numbers do not match spec" message.

Comment: `count` (in the edited version) counts the number of incorrect entries. If all are correct it will be 0. Your code then has the conditional `if(number.length() == 32 && count > 1){`

Answer (score 0):

for comparing a char you should use

```
if(number.chartAt(i) == '0')
```

another issue is  number.charAt(0) will give you char not  int. so when you are doing

```
number.charAt(0)+number.charAt(1) //you are concatenating character at index 0 and index 1
// do this
int first = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(0,1));
int second = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(1,2));
if( (first+second)%2 == 1){
    // your statement
}
```

Comment: I didn't even notice that mistake. Thank you! When I tried to modify that for my for loop, I couldn't make it work:    if((symmDiff + number.substring(i, i + 1)) % 2 == 1){    I've never used substring before. It complained about the mod operator in this portion.

Comment: Wait, I changed that and added for(int i = 2; i < number.length(); i++){
    
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(i,i + 1));
    if((symmDiff + num1) % 2 == 1){   ---does that look correct? I think it's working. Still testing.

Comment: What is `if ((symmDiff + num1) % 2 == 1` all about? From what I can tell, it's equivalent to `if (symmDiff != num1)`.